# How to lay temporal audio file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to reproduce an audio that I previously recorded and I have it into the tmp folder.

My problem is, How can I pass this file to the audio_tag helper in the view? can I build a temporary asset, or something like that?

Controller:

```
  def confirm_audio_legal
    @audio = "#{Constants::TEMP_FOLDER}/#{params[:filename]}"
    render layout: false
  end
```

View:

```
<p>Bla bla bla</p>

<audio src="<%=@audio%>" controls>

<br>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I respond myself.
Just add a controller for send the audio file like this:

Page Controller:

```
  def confirm_audio_legal
    @audio = "tmp_audio/#{params[:filename]}"
    render layout: false
  end
```

Controller which serve the file:

```
class AudioSenderController < ActionController::Base

  def send_audio
    # Add some security
    audio = File.open("#{Constants::TEMP_FOLDER}/#{params[:filename]}")
    send_file audio
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
get 'tmp_audio/:filename', to: 'audio_sender#send_audio'
```